# Incremental search shortcut in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Can I do "incremental search" / "incremental find" in Visual studio code, similar to eclipse and regular Visual studio? I think it's ctrl+j in eclipse and ctrl+i in visual code.

What it does is that it enables typing anywhere in the file and highlighting matches.

Comment: I take it that you do not want to do  Ctrl-F and type in that find panel. It will perform an incremental search with highlighting.

Comment: No, becuase I need to press ESC to get back to the editor

Comment: [This plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=siegebell.incremental-search) might help.

Answer (score 3):

So I had the same issue, and the plugin that [wardw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/254035/wardw) found did not work with ctrl+g to cancel the search and return to editing.  It turns out that [siegebell](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/publishers/siegebell), the original author of that plugin, posted a bug to the visual studio code people regarding this, and they eventually added the capability to cancel the window, but the plugin hasn't been updated in awhile.

I decided to fork the plugin, and update it myself to work.  [Link here.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ATPSoft.emacs-incremental-search)

Comment: @Kern Mason - you sir (or madam) are a life saver --- this is terrific. Question though - is there any way to change the bindings from ctrl-S to something else if one chooses?

Comment: @David - you can -- it's easy in Visual Studio Code -- for this case, you can go: View -> Command Palette -> Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts -> extension.incrementalsearch.forward -- edit both entries (editorTextFocus and incrementalSearch) by mousing over and selecting the pen symbol on the left, it'll let you press a new key combination to set the shortcut to.  The instructions here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#:~:text=All%20keyboard%20shortcuts%20in%20VS,of%20the%20editor%20title%20bar. may also be relevant.